# insert footnotes into all on a new page using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to insert footnote based on users selection.

doc.Footnotes.Add(wordSelection.Range, ref missing, footnote);

However I would like to have all the footnotes display on a new page if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Footnotes can be displayed only

1. After the text
2. At the bottom of the page

There is no option to force them to display on a new page.

**End notes** can be

1. at the end of a section
2. at the end of the document.

By inserting a page break at the end of the document, just before the endnotes begin, you can force them to be on a new page. Here's some code that removes the EndNote separator and inserts a page break before the endnotes (at the end of the main document story)

```
Sub PageBreakBeforeEndNotesAndNoSeparator()
  Dim rngDoc As word.Range, rngEndNoteSep As word.Range

  Set rngDoc = ActiveDocument.content
  Set rngEndNoteSep = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdEndnoteSeparatorStory)
  rngEndNoteSep.Delete
  rngDoc.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rngDoc.InsertBreak word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
End Sub
```